# Two ListViews in a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, scrollview

I know that it is not best practice to put two ListViews in a ScrollView. However, it is the best solution I can think of for my problem:

I want two lists (the first one consisting of 1-5 items and the last one with a maximum of 20 items) beneath each other in a scrollable view, each with it's own header. The ListViews should not be scrollable themselves, they should just change height to wrap their content. The scrollable part would be handled by the ScrollView.

Because the ListView doesn't support this natively i am using the following code:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "TotalHeight:" + totalHeight);
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listAdapter.getCount() * listView.getDividerHeight());
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

However, this makes the ListViews about 10x larger then they should be. If I search for the problem I'm having I always find the above solution but for me this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to fix my code or is there a better way to go at this?

XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.miscoriadev.svvirgoapp.fragments.frag_activiteiten"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_acti_komende_activiteiten"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:text="Komende activiteiten"
            android:textColor="@color/TextColorDark"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_acti_komende_activiteiten"
            android:id="@+id/lv_komende_activiteiten">
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:text="Afgelopen activiteiten"
            android:textColor="@color/TextColorDark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:id="@+id/tv_acti_afgelopen_activiteiten"
            android:layout_below="@id/lv_komende_activiteiten"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_acti_afgelopen_activiteiten"
            android:id="@+id/lv_afgelopen_activiteiten">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need both lists to scroll at the same time and be shown in the same screen? If so, I would recommend to use [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) with 2 columns. If not, I would recommend to use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) with [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). Here is an tutorial of how to do it: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: No, I just want them to be beneath each other and have two lists in one scrollable frame

Comment: I believe it would be more convenient if you use horizontal `ListView`s instead of vertical ones. I'd even recommend using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which can be either horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating my own list UI element from a LinearLayout by inflating views into it like an ListAdapter would do for a ListView.

However a bit crude, you can easily rewrite this code to accept a ListAdapter object as the item source. By rewriting the setListItems() method to get it's views by the getView() method of a ListAdapter object.

```
package com.miscoriadev.svvirgoapp.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.miscoriadev.svvirgoapp.MainActivity;
import com.miscoriadev.svvirgoapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by milanvandijck on 14/10/2016.
 */

public class UnscrollableListView extends LinearLayout{

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

public UnscrollableListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.mainActivity = (MainActivity)context;
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    if(!this.isInEditMode()) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}

public UnscrollableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    this.mainActivity = (MainActivity)context;
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    if(!this.isInEditMode()) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}


public void setListItems(ArrayList<ActivityItem> list){

    for (int i = 0; i <= list.size()-1; i++){
        UnscrollableListView.viewHolder holder = new UnscrollableListView.viewHolder();
        View rowView;
        final ActivityItem item = list.get(i);

        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Adding view: " + item.getTitle());

        // Check if there are activities
        if (item.getTitle().equals("0_0") && item.getLocation().equals("0_0")){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activiteiten_listitem_emptylist, null);
            this.addView(rowView);
        }

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activiteiten_listitem, null, false);

        holder.tv_name=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
        holder.tv_date=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eventDate);
        holder.tv_time=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eventTime);
        holder.tv_Location= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eventLocation);
        holder.img_poster=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.eventPoster);

        holder.tv_name.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.img_poster.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        holder.tv_date.setText(item.getDateString());
        holder.tv_time.setText(item.getTimeString());
        holder.tv_Location.setText(item.getLocation());

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mainActivity.openActivityDetails(item);
            }
        });

        this.addView(rowView, i);
    }

    this.invalidate();

}

public class viewHolder
{
    TextView tv_name;
    TextView tv_date;
    TextView tv_time;
    TextView tv_Location;
    ImageView img_poster;
}
}
```